# Calculating time (adding minutes) bash

Tags: bash, time, date-arithmetic

I got stuck in part of the script. I have time: for example "16:00" and duration in minutes like: 410.

Is there any easy way to add those two values? I've tried a lot of combinations with `date -d`, but can't solve it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this (Kysu's version):

```
date -d "16:00 410 minutes" +'%H:%M'
```

or this:

```
date -d "16:00 today + 410 minutes" +'%H:%M'
```

But **do not** use this:

```
date -d "16:00 + 410 minutes" +'%H:%M'   # BAD!
```

Strange things happen if you omit the word `today` but keep the `+`.  (I think the `+ 410` is being parsed as a timezone modifier, and then the `minutes` is interpreted as "add one minute".)

Comment: well I tried without word `today` now it's OK. Also works well: `date -d "16:00 410 minutes" +'%H:%M'`