# Doing Math With Time Bash

Tags: bash, macos, date, math, time

I have a script I am trying to write where it requires that I am able to do math with time. For example I want to subtract two hours from Feb 12 01:25 so the result should be Feb 11 23:25. However bash does not have built in types so it does not make this an easy task as it would be in any other programming language.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/408775/add-seconds-to-a-given-date-in-bash

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208473/calculating-time-adding-minutes-bash

Comment: @Barmar I have found questions and answers like the one you posted but they don't work for me they just echo what would happen.  Ex i wrote                     
`newtime= date -d "16:00 410 minutes" +'%H:%M'
echo $newtime`                                                                                          and the console output                                                                         
`usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804966/date-command-does-not-follow-linux-specifications-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: @Barmar Thanks so much that was the answer i needed!