# Date time incermentor in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to print a value[1 hour increment] like this for yesterday date in bash script. Please help
Output like below.

```
FROM_DATE : 2018-04-23T000000Z TO_DATE : 2018-04-23T005959Z
FROM_DATE : 2018-04-23T010000Z TO_DATE : 2018-04-23T015959Z
FROM_DATE : 2018-04-23T020000Z TO_DATE : 2018-04-23T025959Z
```

My code:
I'm able to fetch hour using below code. I can't able to do for minutes

```
start='date +%s'

FROM_DATE=$(date -d "1 day ago" +%Y-%m-%d"T"%H%M%S"Z")

for i in {0..23}

do 
    start='date +%s'

    FROM_DATE=$FROM_DATE

    TO_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d"T"%H%M%S"Z" -d "1 day ago""$date + $i hour")

     echo "FROM_DATE : $FROM_DATE"

     echo "TO_DATE : $TO_DATE"

     FROM_DATE=$TO_DATE

done
```

[Update Code] - Giving correct output, Please let me know for any optimization or modification -

```
start='date +%s'

FROM_DATE=$(date -d "1 day ago" +%Y-%m-%d"T"%H"0000""Z")

for i in {0..5}

do 
  echo "FROM_DATE : $FROM_DATE"

  TO_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d"T"%H"5959""Z" -d "1 day ago""$date + $i hour")

  echo "TO_DATE : $TO_DATE"

  FROM_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d"T"%H"0000""Z" -d "1 day ago""$date + $i hour""$date + 1 hour")

done
```

Comment: There are a lot of problems here, it decreases your chances to obtain a meaningful answer... Start by removing the first two lines of your loop as they're useless (you don't ever use `$start`, and `FROM_DATE=$FROM_DATE` has no effect), change the calculation of your `TO_DATE` to be based on `$FROM_DATE` rather than the inexistant `$date`, don't add `$i hours` to it but rather a single one since the `FROM_DATE` it's based on is already updated at each iteration, don't repeat the `-d 1 day ago` since it's already present in the `FROM_DATE`.

Comment: its not clear if you want to print starting from 00:00:00 yesterday or time right now yesterday. Also do u want to print till 23:59:59 yesterday or this time yesterday to this time today

Answer (score 0):

Adding minutes works similarly to what you did with hours:

```
TO_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d"T"%H%M%S"Z" -d "1 day ago""$date + $i minutes")
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208473/calculating-time-adding-minutes-bash).